# How to reduce the number of reads and writes to Google App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would appreciate, if you could help me **minimize the number of reads and writes** in my quite simple "application". I am new to this, so please be gentle :)

My app is basically a quiz with **~120 questions split over ~20 pages of ~6 questions per page all written to the same "table"**. Depending on how my students reply to certain questions, they will be sent back to earlier questions or the wording of subsequent questions may change. At the end of the quiz, the app calculates a score for each student based on the number of correctly answered questions.

Problems start when over 40 people take the quiz at the same time or on the same day. I get error messages about exceeding quotas and the number of reads and writes to the datastore.

If I understand correctly, my database is too big which results in an Exploding Search: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/

**Would splitting the database into, say, 20 databases of 6 questions solve the problem?**

I have to make it work before Wednesday and I do not have the means to test this solution myself.

Thanks!

Here is how I create my database:

```
class ExpQuestionnaires(db.Model):
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    username= db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi_happy = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi_pleasant = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi_good = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    nmi_interested = db.StringProperty(required=False)    
    ai_content = db.TextProperty(required=False)
    aic = db.TextProperty(required=False)
    dm1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm5 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm6 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm7 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm8 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm9 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm10 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm11 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm12 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm13 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm14 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm15 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm16 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm17 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm18 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm19 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm20 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm21 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm22 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm23 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm24 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm25 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm26 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm27 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm28 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm29 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm30 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm31 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm32 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm33 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm34 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm35 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    dm36 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    soep1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    soep2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    soep3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    soep4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    RteM1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    RteM2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    RteM3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    RteM4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc5 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc6 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc7 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc8 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc9 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc10 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc11 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc12 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc13 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc14 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc15 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc16 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc17 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc18 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc19 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc20 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc21 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc22 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc23 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc24 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc25 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc26 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc27 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc28 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    loc29 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis5 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis6 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bis7 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bas1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bas2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bas3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    bas4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei5 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei6 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei7 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei8 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei9 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    rei10 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp5 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp6 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp7 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp8 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp9 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp10 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp11 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    imp12 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo1 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo2 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo3 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo4 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo5 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo6 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo7 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo8 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo9 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    demo10 = db.StringProperty(required=False)
    pQuizAttempts = db.IntegerProperty(required=False)
    eQuizAttempts = db.IntegerProperty(required=False)
```

Here is how I save answers to questions dm1, dm2, dm3, dm4, dm5, dm6:

```
class RteDM1(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("RteDM1.html")

    def post(self):
        dm1 = self.request.get("DM1")
        dm2 = self.request.get("DM2")
        dm3 = self.request.get("DM3")
        dm4 = self.request.get("DM4")
        dm5 = self.request.get("DM5")
        dm6 = self.request.get("DM6")
        username = self.request.cookies.get('username', 0)

        dmdata = ExpQuestionnaires(username = username, dm1 = dm1, dm2 = dm2, dm3 = dm3, dm4 = dm4, dm5 = dm5, dm6 = dm6)
        dmdata.put()

        next = self.request.get("next")
        if next == "yes":
            self.redirect('/RteDM2')
```

I do not rely on saving data to cookies to make cheating harder (long story) and to have at least partial answers in case my app or student's computer crash.

Here is a webpage with these questions:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
        body {width:900px; margin:20px auto 10px;background-color:#F0F8FF; font-size:16px; font-family:Arial;line-height:1.5em; text-align:justify;}
    .screen { text-align:center; font-style: italic; }
    .bold { text-align:center; font-weight: bold; }
    .normal { text-align:center; font-weight: normal; line-height:30px}
    a.next { text-align:center; padding:2px 5px; margin:0 47%; border:3px outset #ddd; background-color:#DDD;text-decoration: none;}
    li {padding:5px 0}
    input {margin:7px 10px 5px 15px}
    input[type="submit"]{margin:15px 47%;}
    .button {margin:15px 47%; width:100px}
    .width1 {width:7% !important;text-align:center;padding:10px 2px;font-size:12px; }
    .width2 {width:50% !important;text-align:left;padding:2px;}
    td {margin:0 5px 0 0}
    table {font-size:12px;  border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;}
    table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;padding:3px 10px;text-align:center;}
   </style>
</head>

<body>
    <p style="text-align:right;font-size:12px">3/17</p>
<p>Instructions</p>

<form method="post">
<p></p><br>
<table>
        <tr>
        <td class="width2"></td>
        <td class="width1">1 <br/>very unlikely</td>
        <td class="width1">2 <br/>unlikely</td>
        <td class="width1">3 <br/>possibly unlikely</td>
        <td class="width1">4 <br/>hard to tell</td>
        <td class="width1">5 <br/>possibly likely</td>
        <td class="width1">6 <br/>likely</td>
        <td class="width1">7 <br/>very likely</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="width2">Scenario 1</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM1" value="7"></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="width2">Scenario 2</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM2" value="7"></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="width2">Scenario 3</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM3" value="7"></td>    
      </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="width2">Scenario 4</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM4" value="7"></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="width2">Scenario 5</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM5" value="7"></td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="width2">Scenario 6</td
>        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="1"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="2"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="3"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="4"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="5"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="6"></td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="DM6" value="7"></td>    
      </tr>
</table>
  <p class="button"><button type="submit" name="next" value="yes">Next</button></p>
```

Comment: Do you need queries by Qiestions/Answers? You are going to save a LOT of writes if you simply add `indexed=False` to each property in your model that doesn't need querying. Or even better, instead of having a property for each question/answer - save them in a single JSON-like structured property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writes are related to the number of entities saved, and reads are related to the number of entities that you retrieve.

We cannot re-write your application for you, but here are a few tips to save costs:

1. Only index properties that you use in your queries. All other properties should be unindexed (indexed=False). This change will significantly reduce the number of datastore operations and the size of your data with very little effort.
2. There is no need to put all questions into a single entity as properties. Now every time you want to save a response to a single question, you rewrite the whole entity incurring all the corresponding costs. Each question should be a separate entity - possibly a child entity of the Questionnaire entity. Then you can save each response individually at minimal cost. This change will most likely reduce the number of datastore operations for your app by 10-20 times.

Comment: Thank you. 


Just to make sure I understand the second point, you are suggesting that transpose my Questionnaire kind (table)? That is, instead of having entities (rows) equal to unique names with properties (fields) equal to answers to questions, I would have entities (rows) equal to answers to questions with properties (fields) equal to unique names. Is that correct?


This would reduce the number of writes basically because there are fewer students than questions?

Comment: It will :), but I suggest something very different: each response should be a separate entity. Basically, you will have a table with three columns: studentID (or student name, if you prefer), question ID, response. Each response will be a row in this table - it will be cheap to add as there are only 3 properties (columns).

Comment: Thanks! I have selected your answer because it was the most actionable.

Answer (score 0):

Well - the question is, do you need to save the answers every time the users switch  to the next page?
You could also keep the data on the server (session object) and only save to the database at the end of the process.

Also make sure that you keep your indexed properties low:

> *New Entity Put (per entity, regardless of entity size): 2 writes + 2 writes per indexed property value + 1 write per composite index value*

There is no (direct) need to index on the questions or pages.
When a user goes back to a page you can just retrieve all questions and let your backend code send the correct questions of the page to the frontend.

I am not a fan of writing a seperate entity per question - that will cause you to do much more reads on your repo.
Also - it is a very normalized approach - which might not work for your app.

Think for your schema more about: how is your application being used?
What is easiest for me? 1 entity for the entire quiz per user? 1 entity per page? 1 entity per question.
If you want to limit reads and writes => select the design you need based on the above writer count.
And think about how many times you will need to read your entities.
Just write out 1 or 2 scenarios per design and do the math.